# How to make sure the input length is a multiple of 16, and if not add padding to it

Tags: python

basically i want to have an inputted message, and if it is not a value of 16 add random letters to it to make its length a multiple of 16

this is my current code:

```
import math

s = "IYGGRTOCTOERGTDKHUTAOHEIIATTOICNNRIHDSRGKENEACA!"
i = 16
rows = [s[x:x+i] for x in range(0, len(s), i)]
    #print('\n'.join(rows))
columns = list(zip(*rows))
print i, columns
```

This does nothing fancy and insteadjust splits the input up every 16 characters and takes the first letter from each coulmn then outputs it etc, a very basic transpoistion cypher

so what i am trying to do it figure out if s is a multiple of 16, and if not add some random letters to s until it is
so how can i achieve this in python ?

thanks guys

Comment: the input is a string. do you mean the length of the string is multiple of 16?

Comment: yes so i want to check that `"IYGGRTOCTOERGTDKHUTAOHEIIATTOICNNRIHDSRGKENEACA!"` is a multiple of 16

Comment: you're not listening. you made the same error, again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First you calculate how many "extra" characters you have:

```
extra = len(s) % 16
```

Then, there are two possibilities:

## extra > 0

You calculate how much padding you will need to fill a 16-character block:

```
padsize = 16 - extra
```

Finally, you add `padsize` padding characters (perhaps a space ) at the end:

```
s = s + (' ' * padsize)
```

## extra == 0

`s` is ok the way it is.

## Putting everything together

and not using `padsize`:

```
extra = len(s) % 16
if extra > 0:
    s = s + (' ' * (16 - extra))
```

## With random padding

Of course, `' '` is not the only padding possible. You can use [`random.choice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) to pick a character from a certain list and use that as padding.

There are some nice predefined lists of characters, you can either use [`string.letters`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.letters) and the like:

```
padding = random.choice(string.letters)
```

or use your own list of possible paddings:

```
padding = random.choice("x|#_ ")
```

So, putting everything together again:

```
import string
import random

padding = random.choice(string.letters)
extra = len(s) % 16
if extra > 0:
    s = s + (padding * (16 - extra))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed walk through it has really helped, one quetion instead of the space, is it possible to select a character at random ?

Comment: Yes, I have extended the answer covering that.

Answer (score 4):

```
import math
import string
import random

s = "IYGGRTOCTOERGTDKHUTAOHEIIATTOICNNRIHDSRGKE"

while len(s) % 16 !=0:
    s = s + random.choice(string.letters)

# s is now a multiple of 16 random characters
# continue processing
```